# React Native Maps on Android

Tags: android, react-native

I folllowed the steps and created the container as said by air-bnb installation guide. I am seeing a google logo at the bottom of the container so that means my initialization steps are correct but the map content is not loading. I am including the api key in my manifest as :

```
<meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
     android:value="mydummmmmmmmmmyApiKeyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"/>
```

Is it even correct? The doc seems to say to put it between two brackets as:

```
<meta-data
         android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
         android:value="{{mydummmmmmmmmmyApiKeyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy}}"/>
```

I have tried both and was not successful.

**Edit : Solved**

The map was visible after restarts

The correct way to use the api key is to include this in manifest

```
<meta-data
             android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
             android:value="mydummmmmmmmmmyApiKeyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
If you have a blank map issue, (#118, #176) try the following lines :

Set this Stylesheet in your map component

...
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
   ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
   height: 400,
   width: 400,
   justifyContent: 'flex-end',
   alignItems: 'center',
 },
 map: {
   ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
 },
});

module.exports = class MyApp extends React.Component {
 render() {
   const { region } = this.props;
   console.log(region);

   return (
     <View style ={styles.container}>
       <MapView
         style={styles.map}
         region={{
           latitude: 37.78825,
           longitude: -122.4324,
           latitudeDelta: 0.015,
           longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
         }}
       >
       </MapView>
     </View>
   );
 }
}
Run "android" and make sure every packages is updated.
If not installed yet, you have to install the following packages :
Extras / Google Play services
Extras / Google Repository
Android 6.0 (API 23) / Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image Rev. 13
Check manual installation steps
Generate your SHA1 key :
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

Go to Google API Console and select your project, or create one.
In Overview -> Google Maps API -> Google Maps Android API -> Check if it's enabled
Create a new key by clicking on Create credentials -> API Key -> Android Key, enter the name of the API key and your SHA1 key, generated before, and create it. Check installation step 4.

Clean the cache :
watchman watch-del-all
npm cache clean

When starting emulator, make sure you have enabled Wipe user data.

Run react-native run-android

At this step it should work, but if not, go to your Google API Console and create a Browser key instead of a Android key and go to step 6.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was able to solve it with restarts.